# C# event is null even though it is subscribed

Tags: c#, events

I have a Flight class and a Form class, I want to send Log messages to a textfield from the Flight class to the Form.

I have an already working one for another class called Airport, but this one is practically identical, yet the event `LogMessage` is always null, even after subscribing.

-- MainForm --

```
namespace FlightSim
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        Airport airport = new Airport();
        Luggage luggage = new Luggage();
        Flight flight = new Flight();
        DAO db = new DAO();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeEvents();
        }

        private void InitializeEvents()
        {
            this.airport.ErrorMessage += new System.EventHandler(OnErrorReceived);
            this.flight.LogMessage += new System.EventHandler(OnLogReceived);
        }

        public void OnErrorReceived(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string msgContent = ((Airport.MessageEventArgs)e).msgContent;
            this.mainLog.AppendText(msgContent);
        }

        public void OnLogReceived(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string msgcontent = ((Flight.MessageEventArgs)e).msgContent;
            this.mainLog.AppendText(msgcontent);
        }
    }
}
```

-- Flight --

```
namespace FlightSim
{
    public class Flight
    {
        public class MessageEventArgs : System.EventArgs
        {
            public string msgContent;
        }

        public event System.EventHandler LogMessage;
        DAO db = new DAO();

        public Flight(string flightNumber, string departure, string destination, int totalLoadCapacity)
        {
            this.FlightNumber = flightNumber;
            this.Departure = departure;
            this.Destination = destination;
            this.TotalLoadCapacity = totalLoadCapacity;
            //LogMessage += (s, o) => { };
        }

        public void StartFlight()
        {
            string tmpDeparture = this.Departure;
            string tmpDestination = this.Destination;
            this.OnLogUpdate("Taking off from " + tmpDeparture + " now.");
            this.Destination = tmpDeparture;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.OnLogUpdate("Arriving in " + tmpDestination + " now.");
            this.Departure = tmpDestination;
        }

        protected void OnLogUpdate(string logMessage)
        {
            if (logMessage == "")
                return;

            MessageEventArgs e = new MessageEventArgs();
            var handler = LogMessage;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                e.msgContent = logMessage;
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what can be the cause for an event being `null` even though it is subscribed?

Comment: Are you sure that `StartFlight()` is not called before `InitializeEvents()`? For example, in `Form_Load()`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert He does not mention it throwing a `NullReferenceException`, probably because he checks it. It can still be null.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: OP hasn't mentioned the `NullRefernceException` in this code but in his last question. So i assume that this code snippet already prevents the exception but the EventHandler  `LogMessage` is still null. So the problem is that the event can't be raised.

Comment: @DionV. Yes, i'm Very sure, since StartFlight() is called when i press a button, and InitializeEvents is called as part of the Form creation. and I'l look into that MCVE thing in a moment

Comment: Also, are you sure you are not creating a new `Flight` somewhere else? Made me think you might do that since you have a constructor with arguments, but you are creating (and using) one without arguments.

Comment: @DionV. ! ofcourse I am, and i assume now, that it won't be working properly then :/ How would i go about subscribing to all Flight objects i create?

Comment: I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the constructor with arguments and the initialization without arguments, you probably are creating another `Flight` class somewhere else. All you have to do is make sure that you subscribe the same event upon creation. Do something like this;

```
Flight someOtherFlight = new Flight("1", "Amsterdam", "Hong Kong", 500);
someOtherFlight.LogMessage += new System.EventHandler(OnLogReceived);
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This MCVE works fine

Program.cs

```
namespace StackOverflowPlayground
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sim = new AirportSim();
            sim.flight.StartFlight();
        }
    }
}
```

FlightSim.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace StackOverflowPlayground
{
        public class AirportSim
        {
            public Flight flight = new Flight("1","","",1);

            public AirportSim()
            {
                InitializeEvents();
            }

            private void InitializeEvents()
            {

                flight.LogMessage += OnLogReceived;
            }

            public void OnLogReceived(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                string msgcontent = ((Flight.MessageEventArgs)e).msgContent;
                Console.WriteLine(msgcontent);
            }
        }
    public class Flight
    {
        public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public string msgContent;
        }

        public event EventHandler LogMessage;

        public Flight(string flightNumber, string departure, string destination, int totalLoadCapacity)
        {
            FlightNumber = flightNumber;
            Departure = departure;
            Destination = destination;
            TotalLoadCapacity = totalLoadCapacity;
            //LogMessage += (s, o) => { };
        }

        public string Destination { get; set; }

        public int TotalLoadCapacity { get; set; }

        public string Departure { get; set; }

        public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

        public void StartFlight()
        {
            string tmpDeparture = this.Departure;
            string tmpDestination = this.Destination;
            OnLogUpdate("Taking off from " + tmpDeparture + " now.");
            Destination = tmpDeparture;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            OnLogUpdate("Arriving in " + tmpDestination + " now.");
            Departure = tmpDestination;
        }

        protected void OnLogUpdate(string logMessage)
        {
            if (logMessage == "")
                return;

            var e = new MessageEventArgs();
            var handler = LogMessage;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                e.msgContent = logMessage;
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `this.flight.LogMessage += new System.EventHandler(OnLogReceived);` <== sets that LogMessage

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling that before you first call OnLogUpdate()? Have you put in breakpoints and verified that it is being set up the way you want it to?

Comment: @CBauer Yes, adding breakpoints at both the initializeEvents and the OnLogUpdate() causes a break at the InitializeEvents first and then at the OnLogUpdate when i press a button set to call OnLogUpdate()

Comment: Your code is doing something different, because I just implemented it in a console app and it works fine (see my edit).

Comment: @CBauer Alright thanks, I'l look it all over again, but thanks =)

Comment: I'd double check that you're using the flight from inside the "sim" class in your testing, because that tripped me up initially per the line `sim.flight.StartFlight();`